# How many times approximately can I execute this Azure function each month using the free grant?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have developed a Azure function in Python and each execution costs this much resources :

[image: Graph]

As the Azure consumption plan provides a free grant of **4,00,000 GB-s / month**. **How many times can I execute this function** for free per month? How to do that calculation?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-consumption-costs

Comment: @CSharpRocks Can you please help me calculate how many times approximately I can execute based on the above data?

Comment: In your situation, it is basically 1000,000 executions. Please have a look of my answer.:)

Comment: Any update of this question?

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, It is basically 1000,000 executions.

Free limit of consumption plan has two standard.

**First:**

```
{The computing resources(GB)} * {the time your function execute} <= 400,000
```

**Second:**

```
{Total execute times} <= 1000,000
```

From your description of your question, the spend of unit computing resource is not very large. But not matter how small of your spend of unit computing resource, it only free for 1000,000 executions.

This is the pricing calculator:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=functions

And please notice that the above free limit of your function is based on plan, but not function app. So if you have two function app, and both of them are using the same plan, then the free limit you need to calculate both of them.

Let me know whether this can answer your question.:)